# from which class super and this methods belongs?

Tags: java

from which class these methods super() and this() belongs? and on which class instance(object) these methods called in our class constructor ? are they are from class Object? are they called on current instance this.super() ?

Comment: They are not methods, they are Java keywords.

Comment: buddy this and super are keyword as well as methods its all depends on us how we use them.                                                            class A{

Comment: class A
{
int a;
A(){
this(5); //this method my Q-from which class this() belongs? is this from class Object
}
A(int a)
{
this.a=a; this keyword
}
}

Answer (score 2):

**super()** is used to invoke super class no-arg constructor.If there is no super class specified,it calls the constructor of java.lang.Object(the implicit super class).

**this()** is used to call a no-arg constructor from another overloaded constructor.

Note:-

```
1) super() and this () can be called from contructors only.They cannot be treated as methods.
2)A constructor will have to call super() at one point of time otherwise stack will explode.
3)They are the first statement in the body of a constructor and thus only one can be used at a time.
```